# Puppet module missing dependency

Tags: centos-7, puppet

`puppet module install $module` does not seem to work properly in Centos 7.

```
[root@client modules]# puppet module install spacepants-ds_389
Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppet/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/etc/puppet/modules
└─┬ spacepants-ds_389 (v1.1.7)
  ├─┬ puppetlabs-concat (v4.2.1)
  │ └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.25.1)
  └─┬ puppetlabs-inifile (v2.5.0)
    └── puppetlabs-translate (v1.2.0)
```

The module downloads just fine and seem to satisfy the required dependencies, but listing the result states the the dependencies are unmet:

```
[root@client modules]# puppet module list  --tree
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-concat':
  'spacepants-ds_389' (v1.1.7) requires 'puppetlabs-concat' (>=4.0.0 <5.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-inifile':
  'spacepants-ds_389' (v1.1.7) requires 'puppetlabs-inifile' (>=1.0.0 <3.0.0)
Warning: Missing dependency 'puppetlabs-stdlib':
  'spacepants-ds_389' (v1.1.7) requires 'puppetlabs-stdlib' (>=4.2.0 <5.0.0)
/etc/puppet/modules
├─┬ spacepants-ds_389 (v1.1.7)
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY puppetlabs-concat (>=4.0.0 <5.0.0)
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY puppetlabs-inifile (>=1.0.0 <3.0.0)
│ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY puppetlabs-stdlib (>=4.2.0 <5.0.0)
├─┬ puppetlabs-inifile (v2.5.0)
│ └── puppetlabs-translate (v1.2.0)
└─┬ puppetlabs-concat (v4.2.1)
  └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.25.1)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

Why is that?

```
puppetlabs-concat v4.2.1 >= 4.0.0
puppetlabs-inifile v2.5.0 >= 1.0.0
puppetlabs-stdlib v4.25.1 >= 4.2.0
```

Version numbers look OK to me.

Comment: `puppet --version` gives `3.6.2` which is alot less than the `Puppet >= 4.7.0` that the module requires. Might be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Default version of puppet on centos 7 was the problem.

Installing the repo for puppet 5 and using it worked better:

```
# yum erase puppet
# rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
# yum install puppet
```

then all ok:

```
[root@client ~]# /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module install spacepants-ds_389
Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppet.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└─┬ spacepants-ds_389 (v1.1.7)
  ├─┬ puppetlabs-concat (v4.2.1)
  │ └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.25.1)
  └─┬ puppetlabs-inifile (v2.5.0)
    └── puppetlabs-translate (v1.2.0)
[root@client ~]# /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list --tree
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└─┬ spacepants-ds_389 (v1.1.7)
  ├─┬ puppetlabs-concat (v4.2.1)
  │ └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.25.1)
  └─┬ puppetlabs-inifile (v2.5.0)
    └── puppetlabs-translate (v1.2.0)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules (no modules installed)
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```